# Is there an Integral domain that is a GCD domain but NOT a UFD?

Tags: integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

For most Integral domains I found that are Not UFD, they just does not have the uniqueness of factorization, while they still possess the existence of factorization. ($\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ for example)

I searched on Wiki and found that the Uniqueness corresponds to being in a GCD domain, and Existence corresponds to Accending Chain Condition of Principal ideal(ACCP)

So, I am wondering is there any integral domain between the GCD domain & UFD?

Comment: Check the examples section of this Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain